# Rewrite SQL without cursor for Data Warehouse

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have SQL code (main core) below that works fine on SQL Server. How to rewrite it for T-SQL Azure SQL DW, which doesn't like cursor? I didn't find appropriate example and can't do it myself.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE calc_balance

CREATE TABLE output_table (Amount FLOAT, ValueStart FLOAT, ValueStop FLOAT);

DECLARE cursor_1 CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT Criteria, Amount, ValueStart, ValueStop 
    FROM Input_table

OPEN cursor_1

WHILE @fetchstatus = 0 
BEGIN
    FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_1 INTO @Criteria, @Amount, @ValueStart, @ValueStop;

    @ValueStart1 = @balance;
    @ValueStop1 = @ValueStart1 + @Amount;

    IF (@Criteria = 1) AND (@balance> -100) 
    BEGIN
        @Amount = 0;
        @ValueStop1 = @ValueStart;
    END;

    @balance = @balance + @Amount + @ValueStart;

    INSERT INTO output_table 
    VALUES (@Amount, @ValueStart1, @ValueStop1);
END;
```

Comment: use `recursive cte`

Comment: Your cursor doesn't have an `ORDER BY` on it, therefore your results are non-deterministic (random, essentially).  Is there a column you can order things by?  Additionally, monetary values (which is implied by things like `@balance` and `@Amount`) shouldn't be stored in a `float` column, but rather a base-10, usually fixed-point, column type (often `DECIMAL` or `NUMERIC`, but other possibilities exist).  Do you have sample starting data and desired results?  What is this statement intended to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try this.

```
with cte as (
    select 0 as ctr, 0 as balance, Criteria, Amount, ValueStart, ValueStop, (select count(1) from Input_table) as ct from Input_table
    union all
    select ctr +1, balance + case when Criteria = 1 and balance >-100 then 0 else Amount end + ValueStart
        , Criteria, Amount, balance
        , case when Criteria = 1 and balance >-100 then balance + Amount else ValueStart end 
        , ct
    from cte
    where ctr < ct
)
Insert into output_table VALUES 
(select  Amount,ValueStart, ValueStop from cte where ctr>0)
```

Comment: Recursive CTEs aren't magic loop creators, they still work on sets.  In this case, your query is going to report every row in `Input_Table` with every updated `ctr` value, which is certainly not intended.  This may stem from the OPs lack of an order criteria (which would be required).  A recursive CTE is likely not the best answer - a windowed `SUM` or similar is more relevant - but may be required.